# exclude specific page from direction code CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

use teachable.com platform and they have an option for a code Snippets (see attached photo #1)
[image]
I added this code

```css
div {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

in order to change the direction of the website to be RTL. the problem this code apply to every page at the the website and some pages I don't want it to be effected by it. is there any way to exclude specific page from this action?

I only have access to edit the website ether by code Snippets or this file  (see attached photo #2)
[image]
which is the file of the page that I need to exclude

Answer (score 0):

You current css selector, affects every `div` on the page. You can use a css class for your right-to-left content:

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="rtl">كيف حالكم</div>

<div>how are you</div>
```